# python crawler ieee paper keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

i trying to use crawler to get ieee paper keywords but now i get a error 
how can to fix my crawler? 
my code is here

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ieee_content = requests.get("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8465981", timeout=180)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ieee_content.text, 'xml')
tag = soup.find_all('script')
for i in tag[9]:
    s = json.loads(re.findall('global.document.metadata=(.*;)', i)[0].replace("'", '"').replace(";", ''))
```

and error is here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/github/爬蟲/redigg-leancloud/crawlers/sup_ieee_keywords.py", line 90, in <module>
    a.get_es_data(offset=0, size=1)
  File "G:/github/爬蟲/redigg-leancloud/crawlers/sup_ieee_keywords.py", line 53, in get_es_data
    self.get_data(link=ieee_link, esid=es_id)
  File "G:/github/爬蟲/redigg-leancloud/crawlers/sup_ieee_keywords.py", line 65, in get_data
    s = json.loads(re.findall('global.document.metadata=(.*;)', i)[0].replace(";", '').replace("'", '"'))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: How is the json object 's' being used in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer.  I don't know what you are doing with 's' in your code after the load (replace) in my code.

The code below doesn't thrown an error, but again how are you using 's'

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ieee_content = requests.get("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8465981", timeout=180)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ieee_content.text, 'xml')
tag = soup.find_all('script')

# i is a list
for i in tag[9]:
   metadata_format = re.compile(r'global.document.metadata=.*', re.MULTILINE)
   metadata = re.findall(metadata_format, i)
   if len(metadata) != 0:
      # convert the list 
      convert_to_json = json.dumps(metadata)
      x = json.loads(convert_to_json)
      s = x[0].replace("'", '"').replace(";", '')
      ###########################################
      # I don't know what you plan to do with 's'
      ###########################################
      print (s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in line 65 some of the data provided in `i` did not suite the regex pattern you're trying to use. Therefor your `[0]` will not work as the data returned is not an array of suitable length.

Solution:

```
x = json.loads(re.findall('global.document.metadata=(.*;)', i)
if x:
    s = x[0].replace("'", '"').replace(";", ''))
```